# Which Preference class I should use to get this view

Tags: android, settings, preference

How can I get this result?

1. [image: Rolling list]
2. [image: Scroll bar]

Whether any of the standard Preference classes like:
-DialogPreference
-EditTextPreference
-MultiSelectListPreference
-SwitchPreference
-TwoStatePreference will allow me to do this? Or I need to use additional libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Use [NumberPickerPreference](https://github.com/vanniktech/VNTNumberPickerPreference.git)

2) Use [SeekBarPreference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/preference/SeekBarPreference.html)